# How to find clique in titan graph database with gremlin?

Tags: graph, neo4j, titan, gremlin

I need to find all [cliques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) of three size from my graph with [Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki). I was able to do this in neo4j with cypher:

```
MATCH (a)-[:edge]-(b)-[:edge]-(c)-[:edge]-(a)
RETURN a,b,c
```

The example case is: A->B->C->A

One possible solution based in answer of @pkohan is:

```
g.V().as('x').sideEffect{x = it}.out().loop(1){it.loops < 4}{if(it.loops==4){if(it.object.id==x.id){true}else{false}}else{false}}.path.dedup().collect{"${it[0].id}->${it[1].id}->${it[2].id}"}
```

Someone has another idea?

Comment: I don't think this should be closed for being too broad.  It's a fairly specific question about cypher to gremlin conversion.  The answer below shows that it's understandable by those familiar with cypher and gremlin graph query languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query that would be extremely inefficient on a large graph, but does what you would expect:

```
g.V().filter{it.out().loop(1){it.loops < 3}.id.filter{i -> it.id == i}.hasNext()}.map
```

This returns a pipe containing vertexes that can point back to themselves after walking three outgoing edges. You can change the number of edges to follow by changing the `it.loops < 3` in the closure. You can do incoming edges by changing `out()` to `in()`, or you can follow either direction by using `both()`. You can also narrow down to edge types by putting them in the parentheses, for example:

```
g.V().filter{it.out("EDGE_TYPE").loop(1){it.loops < 3}.id.filter{i -> it.id == i}.hasNext()}.map
```

I'm unsure if neo4j has optimizations that make this query doable on a large database, but I'd imagine running this query on a titan graph with millions of edges and vertices would be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how return complete path A->-B->C or A->-B->C->A of each found clique?

Comment: It looks like you already solved it above, sorry I should've read just a bit closer!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're using Gremlin2.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V().as('x').both().loop('x') {it.loops < 3}.both().retain('x').path()
==>[v[1], v[3], v[4], v[1]]
==>[v[1], v[4], v[3], v[1]]
==>[v[3], v[4], v[1], v[3]]
==>[v[3], v[1], v[4], v[3]]
==>[v[4], v[1], v[3], v[4]]
==>[v[4], v[3], v[1], v[4]]
```

As you can see, it's 6 times the same clique, just different start- and end-vertices and different paths. Here's how you can deduplicate the result set:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('x').both().except('x').loop('x') {it.loops < 3}.both().retain('x').path().transform {it[0..2].sort()}.dedup()
==>[v[1], v[3], v[4]]
```

Since the path you're looking for has a fixed length, you can also get rid of the loop construct (which should lead to a faster execution):

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').both().as('b').except('a').both().as('c').both().retain('a').path().transform {it[0..2].sort()}.dedup()
==>[v[1], v[3], v[4]]
```

You can do almost the same thing in Gremlin3, but you also have the option to use the new `match`-step to look for the pattern (which should be pretty straightforward if you know how do write the query in Cypher):

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal(standard())
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().match("a",
gremlin>   __.as("a").both().as("b"),
gremlin>   __.as("b").both().as("c"),
gremlin>   __.as("c").both().as("d")).where("a", eq("d")).select("a", "b", "c").map {it.get().values().sort()}.dedup()
==>[v[1], v[3], v[4]]
```